# How to implement a EventListener for KeyCloak Events in Quarkus with Devservices

Tags: docker, keycloak, quarkus

Hay!

I would like to implement a Event Listener in Quarkus that listens to Events from Keycloak.
Keycloak is configured as a devservice in quarkus.

So a Docker Container from Keycloak starts when starting quarkus. Ill try to add the Ability to select a Custom Listener for those Events that Keycloak throws. Especially the register Event would be nice to catch.

Im kind of lost now.

I tryed to implement a EventListenerProvider class

```
package de.hsos.swa.pizza4me;

import org.keycloak.events.Event;
import org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProvider;
import org.keycloak.events.admin.AdminEvent;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyKeycloakEventListener implements EventListenerProvider {
    
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("Event: " + event.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(AdminEvent event, boolean includeRepresentation) {
        System.out.println("Admin Event: " + event.getOperationType());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("close");
    }

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
        System.out.println("The application is starting...");
    }

}
```

but somehow i need to tell keycloak which is started by Quarkus as a devservice to know the Custom Event Class..

how can i make this class used by Keycloak? How can i configure keycloak to use this class to throw Events to it. Whatever i tryed i wasnt able to select any Custom Event Listener in keycloaks confuguration settings.

Anyone got Ideas on how to do this?

It tells me that those custom listeners can be edited on the keycloak server itself. But i have to use quarkus to start it freshly all the time. So i am not able to edit a special keycloak file. Or can i configure quarkus to do so everytime when the docker container started?